# Can I pass parameter to driver during INSMOD or MODPROBE?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I currently worte a USB device driver in which I created a Kthread from probe() function. The general kthread_create() function creates thread on the CPU which is least busy.

What I want to do is create kthread on a particular CPU (kthread_create_on_cpu()), so that I can assign seperate core to device threads dealing with output devices.
How can I pass the CPU number to module when the module/driver is being loaded.

Either I can use a global variable which will be set once when the system boots up and will be read by drivers OR pass CPU number to module while it's being loaded.

Please suggest which method will be more feasible to use and implement.

Thanks and Regards,
Mitesh G

Comment: I get a feeling that this might not be such a good idea. Letting someone specify a non-existent CPU which you then try to use with kthread_create_on_cpu might lead to all kinds of problems.

Comment: Passing Command Line Arguments to a Module http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x323.html

Comment: Hi Sami, The module will be invoked by a process which will have CPU's defined. User will not be allowed to specify the CPU number.

Thankyou Sasi for the link.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass command line arguments. For this you have to add `module_param` or `module_param_array` in module.

Add these lines in your modules of course according to your requirements

`int myintdata = 100;
module_param(myintdata, int, 0);`

`char mychardata = 'A';
module_param(mychardata, char, 0);`

`int myarray[2];
module_param_array(myarray, int, NULL, 0);`

`static char *name;
module_param(name, charp, 0);` // here you have to mention charp as data type

or `module_param_string(name, string, len, perm);` for String

while inserting modules

`insmod module_name.ko myintdata=5 mychardata = 'X' name= "xyz" myarray =99,100`
 `